# Custom selector challenges

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen with a multiple custom selectors, which change what they select based on dropdown lists.

The solution I implemented is shown in a previous case:
[Dynamically changing PXSelector in Acumatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053983/dynamically-changing-pxselector-in-acumatica) (thanks).

My challenge is twofold:

1.) If the dropdown selection is "No Lookup", then I want the PXSelector Attribute to essentially be removed - leaving just a text entry.  Not sure if this is even possible...

2.) If one of the selectors (let's say Projects) is selected, I'd like the selection of the following selector (let's say Tasks) to filter based on the Project selected.

Thanks much...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I think the only way to do this is to create your own attribute.

Something like that:

```
public class PXSelectorTextEditAttribute : PXSelectorAttribute
{
    bool selectorMode;
    public PXSelectorTextEditAttribute(Type type, bool selectorOn):base(type)
    { 
         selectorMode = selectorOn; 
    }
    public override void FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(selectorMode)
        base.FieldVerifying(sender, e);
    }

    public static void SwitchSelectorMode(PXSelectorTextEditAttribute attribute, bool onOff)
    {
        attribute.selectorMode = onOff;
    }
}
```

You will be able to turn on and off the 'selector' part of the attribute. With the field verifying turned off you will be able to put any value to the field just like in simple TextEdit field. However, the lookup button in the right end of the field still will be visible. I have no idea how to hide it.

2) This behavior can be implemented easily. You will need something like that(example based on cashaccount):

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<CABankTran.tranID, Where<CABankTran.cashAccountID, Equal<Current<Filter.cashAccountID>>>>))]
```

If you want to see all records when the cashaccount is not defined then you just modify the where clause by adding `Or<Current<Filter.cashAccountID>, isNull>`

Also don't forget to add `AutoRefresh="true"` to the PXSelector in the aspx. Without it your selector will keep the list of the records untill you press refresh inside of it.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.  That helped.